# Use purrr::accumulate function with two if/else conditions in R

Tags: r, if-statement, purrr, reset, accumulate

I need to calculate a cumulative sum (the same constant is added in each iteration) but with two if/else conditions:

1. Total cumulative sum can't be higher than 400;
2. If the cumulative sum reached 400 on the previous iteration, then check the time. If it is nighttime (between 22 pm and 6 am) keep it to 400 before daytime starts, if it's daytime (between 6 am and 22 pm), reset it to 0 and start accumulating again).

When I try to write it, the second if/else doesn't work.
Is it possible to use two conditions with accumulate()? Or maybe it can't account for time because this is an additional variable? I found an example with one if/else on Stack Overflow, so I guess I incorrectly incorporated a second if/else.

I would be grateful if someone can suggest any idea how to do it, including any other different way to solve my task.

```
k_in = 2                              # constant to add in each iteration
tmax = 24*2*60                        # two days in minutes
x <- tibble(time = c(1:tmax),         # vector of time in minutes
            time_h = time/60,         # vector of time in hours
            time2 = (time_h %% 24),   # vector of time in p.m - a.m 
            value = rep(k_in, tmax),  # value to accumulate
            
            Sum = accumulate(value, ~ifelse(.x + .y <= 400, .x + .y, 
                                               ifelse( (time2 >= 22 | time2 < 6), .x, -k_in + .y))))
```

This creates Sum column that accumulates up to 400 and continues to keep it at 400 even if it is daytime already.

If I change the second if/else to the opposite one it is just resetting and accumulating again up to 400 independently from day/night time.

Comment: Whenever you are thinking about using nested `ifelse`s, consider using `dplyr::case_when`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I usually use case_when() function when I need to create names/categories based on multiple conditions. But I cannot follow your thought on how to apply it in the task that I described.

Comment: I have not tested it, but I think your original code would translate into something like this: `...... ~case_when(.x + .y <= 400 ~ .x + .y, time2 >= 22 | time2 < 6 ~ .x, .default = -kn_in + .y)`

Comment: Now I see your point, thank you! I tried modifying my original code to see if it works with case_when and got some interesting results. It creates a new Sum column where in each iteration I have not one value but a vector of length 1: tmax with replicated value (time 1 Sum = 2, time 2 Sum = c(4,4,4,4.. .) , time 3, Sum = c(6,6,6,...) etc. I definitely need to spend more time on the accumulate() and accumulate2() functions to understand them fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `accumulate2` and provide `time2` as another argument. Then refer to arguments ..1, ..2, ..3 in order as follows:

```
Sum = accumulate2(
        value[-1], 
        time2[-1],
        ~if(.x + .y <= 400) ..1 + ..2 else if (..3 >= 22 | ..3 < 6) ..1 else -k_in + ..2,
        .init = first(value))
)
```

Comment: That's right - adding [-1] will remove the first value, so you will have the correct length. Then you can include the `.init` argument for the initial value to use before accumulation.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Ben! It solved my task! <br/> I'm trying to understand the syntax. I can see that if I remove value[-1] or time2[-1] I have an error about the length of the Sum column: <br/>
• Size 2880: Existing data.
• Size 2881: Column `Sum`.
I also see that if we remove .init = first(value) we have the length error too, but a different one: <br/>`.y` must have length 2878, not 2879 <br/> Does it because we create one more iteration using accumulate2()? I can't understand why I didn't have this error in my example of code. If you can explain it I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: Oh, such a quick answer!)) While I was editing mine, you already explained it! Thanks again!